# Linux Device Driver Character Device "Subdirectory"

Tags: linux-device-driver

I'm writing a Linux device driver for a piece of hardware that provides several independent "channels" of data.  There may be multiple devices present on the system, each providing a set of channels, which will be represented as basically independent character devices.

I'm wondering how to create device nodes in /dev that express the hierarchical relationship, e.g.:

```
/dev/mydevice0/chan0
/dev/mydevice0/chan1
/dev/mydevice0/chan2
/dev/mydevice0/chan3

/dev/mydevice1/chan0
/dev/mydevice1/chan1
/dev/mydevice1/chan2
/dev/mydevice1/chan3
...
```

How does one go about creating this kind of heirarchy automatically?  By "automatically" I mean using typical mechanisms that are available on most modern Linux systems (i.e. it's okay to depend on udev, but I don't want to have to make some special script with a bunch of  `mknod` commands in it).  Is this even wise to attempt, or would I be better off generating a unique suffix for each channel, similar to what is done for disk devices, e.g:

```
/dev/mydev0c0
/dev/mydev0c1
...
/dev/mydev1c0
/dev/mydev1c1
...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function device_create() is how you can have your driver create the device nodes, and according to [this short thread](http://lists.kernelnewbies.org/pipermail/kernelnewbies/2013-January/007111.html), you can hardcode the path you want the device to be placed in when you call it. You just need to replace your path separators with exclamation points.

Example path from the linked thread:

"test!power" will be created as: /dev/test/power

[This tutorial](http://sysplay.in/blog/linux-device-drivers/2013/06/character-device-files-creation-operations/) and [my answer to another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24873440/2615940) should help you use device_create() correctly.

Comment: Wow -- I wouldn't have ever guessed that.  Thanks!

Comment: I was unable to test this before posting it, so I hope it works for you. If it doesn't, please come back and unaccept the answer so I know to keep looking. I'm really interested in this problem and never would have guessed this method either.